# get identifier of link given the class jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this piece of html

```
<li><a href="#" id="9000" class="yes vpslink"><img src="x.gif" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="9001" class="no vpslink"><img src="x.gif" /></a></li>


$('.vpslink').click(function(e) {
   var id='i dont know dude'; 
   alert('you clicked on id'+id);
});
```

How do I find the id of this class, link ?

Comment: `var id = "I have no idea what you're talking about dude";` ... but for what it's worth, numeric IDs are invalid. Try using `link_9000` or something similar

Comment: lol, didn't knew what to put ... was just for fun. how do i then change this content; like replace the x.gif by y.gif ? and background color of the 'a' element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.vpslink').click(function(e) {
   var id= $(this).attr('id'); 
   alert('you clicked on id ' + id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the click handler:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: thanks, and how do i then change this content; like replace the x.gif by y.gif ? and background color of the 'a' element ?

Comment: Well, since $(this) is the link element, then $(this).next() will be the img element.  At that point you can set any attribute, such as 'src' with attr() (e.g. $('this').next().attr('src', 'y.gif');)  You can set css styles, such as background, with .css('background', '#aaa')

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.vpslink').click(function(e) {

      // Quick way to get the ID
   var id = this.id;

      // Replace the SRC of the sibling <img> 
   $(this).siblings('img').attr('src', function(i,src) {
        return (src == 'x.gif') ? 'y.gif' : 'x.gif';
   });

});
```

The fastest way to get the ID of the element is to access its DOM property directly with `this.id`.

You can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the sibling `<img>` and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to update the source. The `.attr()` method can take a function as a parameter that returns the value to set.